# Ajax returns error, but it works

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax, sinatra

I'm running an application using Ajax and Sinatra. I want to send a POST parameter into my app.rb file.

- My app.rb

  ```
  post '/game/moves' do
    @square = params[:square]
    puts @square
    content_type :json
    { :success => 'Data successfully transmitted' }.to_json
  end
  ```
- My view

  ```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'moves',
    data: {square:square},
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function() {
      alert("Success");
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(XMLHttpRequest + textStatus + errorThrown);
    }
  });
  ```

It returns the alert "[object Object]error", but on my console, I see that I successfully retrieved the POST parameter. So it works, but I can't get into the "success" part of the code, and instead I'm getting on the error part.

I also tried to replace the json type by the html type, and removed the return value on my app.rb file, to no avail (exact same error).

Comment: Did you look to see what was returned from the server in your console?

Comment: In your error handler, try `console.log(arguments)` and see what gets logged to your javascript console. Also, check the network tab of your browser's dev tools to see that the request is what you expect.

Comment: I'm guessing parseerror ?

Comment: most likely your response isn't valid json, if you're seeing the response in the console.

Comment: please fix url: 'moves' to url: 'game/moves'

Comment: CodeGroover -> My server don't get any result then. 'moves' doesn't need to be fixed.  
    epascarello -> Here it is:1
    2
    127.0.0.1 - - [03/Oct/2013 19:11:03] "POST /game/moves HTTP/1.1"      200 43 0.0011
    127.0.0.1 - - [03/Oct/2013 19:11:04] "GET /game/moves HTTP/1.1" 200 1707 0.0160

1 2 is the correct post parameter that I successfully retrieve.  
    Jason P -> On the error handler (Chrome): ReferenceError:     arguments is not defined
There's nothing logged on the javascript console.  
    Sorry It seems I can't add line breaks on this comment0

Comment: Use this line to correctly inspect your arguments: `console.log(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)`. Those `+` signs are going to cause type coercion on your objects and turn them into incomprehensible strings like `[object Object]`

Comment: that line on the console tells me that textstatus and errorthrown are not defined. XMLHttpRequest returns: function XMLHttpRequest() { [native code] }. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution. Here, I successfully retrieve the params on top ofgetting the "It works !" alert. That was what I wanted.

As you can notice,  I don't set "async" to false. I don't know why I have to do that, nor why it doesn't work when I don't. I don't mind if it is set to false, for it works, but if someone can tell me the possible reason, it would still help me. Thanks.

Here's the full code (the function send is called in an obstrusive way (with a one-line html onclick), because I need the params xi and yi)

- The view

  ```
  function send(xi,yi) {
    info = [];
    info[0] = xi;
    info[1] = yi;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'moves',
      dataType: 'text',
      async: false,
      data: {square:info},
      success: function(token) {
        alert(token)
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
      }
    });
  }
  ```
- App.rb

  ```
  post '/game/moves' do
    if params[:square]
      "It works !"
    end
  end
  ```